# Dynamic Proxy generation with LinFu

Tags: c#, dynamic, proxy, linfu

I am trying to build a dynamic proxy for an interface with LinFu. The proxy should just implement the getter methods of the properties that are defined by the interface and return for instance a value from a dictionary, where the key is the property name.

[link text](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
// The interceptor class must implement the IInterceptor interface
var yourInterceptor = new YourInterceptor();
var proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
IYourInterface proxy = proxyFactory.CreateProxy<IYourInterface>(yourInterceptor);
// Do something useful with the proxy here...
```